# How do I map an through an array of objects and display each object individually? I want each pizza order to show

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am not sure how to iterate through each order and show them as individual orders. The api response looks like this...

0:

Crust: "THIN"

Flavor: "CHEESE"

Order_ID: 2

Size: "S"

Table_No: 5

Timestamp: "2019-12-03T18:21:08.708470"

And can go on to have as many orders as possible. I do not need the Order_ID showing so maybe that is a way to iterate through?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Orders extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            order: "no orders yet",
            crust: "no crust selected",
            // flavor: "no flavor selected",
            // size: "no size selected",
            // table: "place an order first",
            // timestamp: "place an order first"
        };
    }

    handleButtonClick = () => {
        axios.get("/orders").then(response => {
            this.setState({
                orders: response,
                crust: response.data[0].Crust
                // flavor: response.data[0].Flavor
                //etc..
            });
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}></button>
                <h1>orders are:</h1>
                <p>Crust: {this.state.crust}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export { Orders }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could figure out from your codeblock, this should work. Just set the orders array to the response.data and then iterate over the orders array in your render function.

```
   constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            orders: []
        };
    }

    handleButtonClick = () => {
        axios.get("/orders").then(response => {
            this.setState({
                orders: response.data
            });
        })
    }

    render() {
        const orderData = this.state.orders.map(order => {
return })
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}></button>
                <h1>orders are:</h1>
                {this.state.orders.map((order) => (
                    <p>Flavor: {order.flavor}</p>
                    <p>Crust: {order.crust}</p>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have the orders array on your state, you need to iterate on it on the template, using a map and then rendering the elements you need for each order.

Instead of just rendering the crust from the state, you would do something like this:

```js
      {this.state.orders.map((order) => (
        <p>Crust: {order.crust}</p>
      ))}
```

I quickly created [an example CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-currying-urn4b?file=/src/App.js) doing this.